# Calling single/bunch of statements from within VIM on Windows

Tags: vim, batch-file

I am totally new to [Vim](http://www.vim.org) and just two days into learning it. Like every Vim user I am deeply impressed by the speed boost it has given me.

I create Windows batch(.bat) files with numerous `call` statements. Usually I run a single `call` statement with `Run` prompt and use a .bat file for a set of statements. This is done to ensure that the statements provide desired results. I read that it is possible to run similar scenarios from within Vim. Here are some sample statements which form a part of my batch file:
A single line statement:

```
call %VT_BATCH_ROOT%\Menu\Sub-menu\Name "Line Geometry" "" "" "OK"
```

A multi-line scenario:

```
call %VT_BATCH_ROOT%\Menu\Sub-menu\Command "Yes" "c:\temp\folder\file.ext"

call %VT_BATCH_ROOT%\Menu\Sub-menu\Command "No"

call %VT_BATCH_ROOT%\Menu\Sub-menu\Command "Yes" "" "c:\temp\folder\file.ext" "" "" ""
```

Can someone suggest me how can my requirements be achieved?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you want. Could you explain what you want to call from vim? Do you want to run the `.bat` that you are editing?

Comment: I want to execute the `call` statements in the `.bat` I am editing - sometimes single lined, sometimes 3-4 lines. The entire `.bat` file would contain over 100 such `call` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can use `:!` to execute a shell command. For example, type `:!dir` to open a shell and list the current directory. If you already have the command you want to run open as part of the file you are editing, you could copy and paste it in this way.

**Edit:** To execute the current line as a shell command in Windows, you can do `:.w !cmd -`. For multiple lines, you could record a macro that did this and then moved to the next line, and execute the macro as many times as necessary.

Comment: Matthew - please refer to the comment added to the question by me and edit the answer if necessary.